# Kali linux unattended-upgrade does not work

Tags: apt, kali-linux, unattended-upgrades

It looks like unattended-upgrade does not invoke `apt-get update`. After I run `apt-get update` unattended-upgrade works as expected, but that defeats the purpose of using unattended-upgrade.

```
$ sudo unattended-upgrade -d
Initial blacklisted packages: 
Initial whitelisted packages: 
Starting unattended upgrades script
Allowed origins are: ['o=Kali,a=kali-rolling']
pkgs that look like they should be upgraded: 
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                               
fetch.run() result: 0
blacklist: []
whitelist: []
No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
```

edit1:

```
~$ apt-config dump | grep -i unattended  
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
Unattended-Upgrade "";
Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern "";
Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern:: "o=Kali,a=kali-rolling";
```

Comment: Can you show `apt-config dump | | grep -i unattended` ?

Comment: @Bahamut output provided. I compared it with working unattended-upgraded and they look similar. I think something is preventing apt-get update to run in background. I used to run `apt-get update` with cron as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

My config under debian.

```
cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic 
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
```

Check if something missing on your system.

Answer (score 0):

For me i add only

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern{
...
"origin=Kali";
...
}
```